# Why doesn't ContentVersion support getUpdated() or getDeleted() calls?

Tags: contentversion, contentdocument

I'm working on backing up *Documents, Attachments, ContentDocuments, ContentVersions*. It seems that I cannot use `getUpdated()` and `getDeleted()` calls on *ContentDocuments* and *ContentVersions*.

However, I can query using *SystemModstamp* on *ContentVersions* to obtain the corresponding documents that were created during a particular time frame.

Is this the way to go? If this can be done, why was the `getUpdated()` and `getDeleted()` calls are not supported though the object is retrievable?